# Can the Liquid templating markup be used in Coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript, jekyll, liquid

These two are popular technos that come with the Jekyll static site generation. Is it possible to use [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/) markup inside Coffeescript so that Jekyll produces a final Javascript that includes the insertion from Liquid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - or at least not easily.

First of all, Coffeescript doesn't "come" with Jekyll, at least not with the "vanilla" Jekyll.

There is [an extension](https://github.com/brucespang/coffeescript-jekyll-extension) that you can add to Jekyll that preprocesses Coffeescript and transforms it into javascript. This extension parses all *.coffee files and transforms it into *.js files. The Liquid processor isn't involved.

You could try modifying the extension son liquid is involved, but that's not easy.

Also, being an extension means that it can't be used in github pages directly, which might be a downer.